CPU and GPU performance in VASP compilation
I am a researcher looking to start performing DFT calculations using VASP. I am planning to build a new supercomputer for VASP compilation and am trying to determine whether a CPU or GPU would offer better performance. After conducting various investigations, I am having difficulty finding a detailed analysis comparing the VASP DFT calculation performance of specific CPU and GPU products.
CPU: Intel® Xeon® Gold 6530 (32 cores, 2.1GHz, 160MB, 3UPI, 270W) (Total 64 cores)
GPU: NVIDIA L40S GDDR6 48GB PCI-E4.0 x16
I would appreciate it if anyone could share insights on the VASP performance of these two products.
Thank you.

I don't know for certain, but I expect that the performance of VASP on that GPU would be awful. VASP requires good 64-bit (FP64 or "double-precision") floating-point performance, but the L40S is almost entirely comprised of FP32 and lower-precision cores. The FP64 capabilities of the L40S are there simply to ensure that FP64 code will actually run, the performance is 1/64th of the 32-bit (FP32 or "single-precision") performance; see Figure 1 of:
https://images.nvidia.com/aem-dam/en-zz/Solutions/technologies/NVIDIA-ADA-GPU-PROVIZ-Architecture-Whitepaper_1.1.pdf
The stated FP32 performance is 91.6 TFLOPS, which means that the FP64 performance is about 1.43 TFLOPs. This is nowhere near any modern CPU or GPU; that is not to say that the L40S is a bad card in general, the performance for FP32 is very good, it just isn't designed for 64-bit maths.
